# recursion of void function by return command

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I'm stuck with understanding what this function does in the process.
This is a void function which gets int n as an argument. By recursion,this function calculates the n power of a given matrix.
I'm very confused about the return command because it returns the same void function with n-1 as argument.
I'm trying to write this code in mips(assembly), but the confusion has made it very hard for me.

In my knowledge, return command returns some value. So in mips, register v0 has the return value. 
But since this is a void function, it returns nothing. So I just made it jump to the function with argument n-1.

But I'm wondering does it return the address of function??

I'm just confused about the return process of a void function.

Does my mips code mean the same thing with the c code??

```
power:
    addi $t0,$0,1   //t0=1

    be $a0,$t0,exit  //a0 is the argument n. if n==1, return;(which means go to exit)

    // other codes multipying matrix. I'll skip this part

    addi $a0,$a0,-1  //n=n-1; a0 is the argument for power(n-1)

    j power       //jumps to power, which executes power(n-1)
exit:
    /* when the power is over...*/



void power(int n){

    if (n==1) return;

  /*This part is just multiplication of the matrix and it has got nothing to do with the argument. What it does is multiply the matrix to itself regarless of what the argument n is. I'll just skip this part.*/

    return power(n-1);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `void power` function is supposed to be `void`?  It's not calculating much since it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I don’t think this is legal C code. Are you sure it isn’t C++?

Comment: @Nick, it seems from his explanation that it computes the power of the matrix in place, so it doesn’t need to return a value.

Comment: The code would behave exactly the same if the “return” keyword before the recursive call were omitted. Does that make it easier to understand?

Comment: For the purpose of understanding the code, you can ignore the `return` and treat the last line as if it just said `power(n-1);`. The generated code is the same regardless. Technically this isn't valid ISO C, but GCC accepts it unless I compile with `-pedantic`. In C++ I believe it is valid to have the `return`.

Comment: Okay. Then I get it now.  Thank you all for the explanation!!